# How to save costs on ec2 instances if we are going to spin around 500-600 VMs

Tags: amazon-web-services

we need to spin up around 500-600 vms  in aws for our product application to be used by client and we will be installing our software on it , is there any good alternative in terms of cost , rather than using  ec2 instances . any thoughts appreciated .

our broker product is hosted on aws and beside internet users,  we need our brokers to make quote on behalf of customers and they will access application from these vm's .

Comment: What can you tell me about your use case? Are you basically just hosting files? Is everything containerized? Is this some standard website or web service?

Comment: You'll need to supply _much_ more information for any worthwhile answer. Why do you need so many machines? Is it for one client or many clients? Is each individual VM hosting services for only one customer? Or is it multi-tenant? How are you storing data, eg are databases on the same VM or centralized? How do you intend handling scaling during busy/quiet periods? What are the bottlenecks for your system — CPU, RAM or disk latency? The best answer is not to use EC2 at all, but to go serverless, but that would probably require a rearchitecture of your application.

Comment: Hello , we need it for brokers/agents that is our client ,  we want to access our application hosted on aws thru internal VPC and they need separate vm's for their work ,  its not about hosting application , rather than accessing it from aws hosted application in our VPC , its intranet stuff . its not multi tenancy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [reserved instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/) for part or all of your fleet to save up to 75% of their costs.
Or, in some cases, you may use [spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/), which may be much cheaper than on-demand (and even reserved) instances but may be shut down if spot price become higher than your bidding price.

Comment: thnx 1 option can be quite helpful, I am thinking sort of a single machine or server which can host these multiple vm's , like server where concurrently users can login independently , but cost is key factor as i want to save as much as i can , spot instances is not our choice .